# Create dictionary recursively to store occurrences of characters in a string

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I'm trying to solve this problem at the moment. I added my current code after it, but it's not yet working. Ideally, I won't need a global variable but I'm not too sure how to declare the dictionary in the function without the recursive call resetting it each time.

**Question**

Give a recursive implement to the following function:
def appearances(s, low, high)
The function is given a string s, and two indices: low and high (low<=high), which indicate the range of indices that need to be considered.
The function should return a dictionary that stores a mapping of characters to the number of times they each appear in s. That is, the keys of the dictionary should be the different characters in s, and their associated values should be the number of times each of them appears in s.

For example, the call appearances("Hello world", 0, 10) could return:
{'e':1, 'o':2, 'H':1, 'l':3, 'r':1, ' ':1, 'd':1,'w':1}.

Note: A dictionary is a mutable object. Use that property to update the dictionary, returned from your recursive call.

**My code**

```
d = {}


def appearances(s, low, high):
    global d
    if low > high:
        print(d)
    else:
        if s[low] in d:
            d[s[low]] = int(d.get(s[low])) + 1
        else:
            d = {s[low]: 1}
        appearances(s, low + 1, high)
```

Comment: `d[s[low]] = 1` should do it instead of `d = {s[low]: 1}`. Or, a bit more odd, `d.update({s[low]: 1})`. BTW your function does not returns a dictionary

Comment: @DaniMesejo oh wow thank you! I wasn't excepting such small solution. It's definitely better now but I don't think it's working for multiple word strings. And thanks for the note on my return, I've never used dictionaries before haha so I'll definitely look into that.

Comment: So is this considered `solved` or do you still have questions?

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `global`. Use `return` -

```py
def appearances(s, lo, hi, d = {}):
  if lo > hi:
    return d
  try:
    k = s[lo]
    return appearances(s, lo + 1, hi, {**d, k: d[k] + 1})
  except KeyError:
    return appearances(s, lo + 1, hi, {**d, k: 1})
  except IndexError:
    return None
```

```py
print(appearances("hello world", 2, 8))
```

```py
{'l': 2, 'o': 2, ' ': 1, 'w': 1, 'r': 1}
```